# More efficient left join of big table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following (simplified) query

```
select P.peopleID, P.peopleName, ED.DataNumber
from peopleTable P
    left outer join (   
        select PE.peopleID, PE.DataNumber 
        from formElements FE
             inner join peopleExtra PE on PE.ElementID = FE.FormElementID 
        where FE.FormComponentID = 42
    ) ED on ED.peopleID = P.peopleID
```

Without the sub-query this procedure takes ~7 seconds, but with it, it takes about 3minutes.

Given that table `peopleExtra` is rather large, is there a more efficient way to do that join (short of restructuring the DB) ?

More details:

The inner part of the sub-query, e.g.

```
  select PE.peopleID, PE.DataNumber 
        from formElements FE
             inner join peopleExtra PE on PE.ElementID = FE.FormElementID 
        where FE.FormComponentID = 42
```

Takes between <1 and 5 seconds to execute, and returns 95k rows

There are 1500 entries in the peopleTable.

Comment: It's okay as a sub-query as long as peopleExtra is filtered down significantly in the join. If, after the join, there are a large number of resulting rows in your sub-query, then it's probably more appropriate to re-form it into an additional join, as @Orbman has done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is OK, just create the following indexes:

```
PeopleExtra (PeopleID) INCLUDE (DataNumber, ElementID)
FormElements (FormComponentID, FormElementID)
```

Rewriting the join is not required (`SQL Server`'s optimizer can deal with the nested queries just fine), though it can make your query more human-readable.

Comment: these indexes are in place, although the previous coder stuck "with recompile" in the procedure. this seems to be the "quick fix" where I work. seems like a code smell if you ask me!

Comment: I've marked this as correct as it was indeed to do with the optimizer - it turned out it have been optimized incorrectly. reshuffling the rest of the procedure fixed this. unfortunately a bit of a red herring!

Answer (score 1):

how long does that sub-query take to run by itself? If it takes close to 3 minutes, then you need to make the sub-query more effecient on its own - if it takes only a few seconds, then it's the whole statement that needs to be worked on.

Are there any indexes on peopleExtra? Specifically, on that starts with ElementID and includes DataNumber? I suspect the problem is the join inside your subquery that's causing trouble.

Also, can you please include a query plan? Run `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON` before your query and then post the results here - that will help determine what's slowing it down.

Comment: unfortunately the query itself is 130 lines longer than the given example, so I cant include the actual execution plan. It's definitely the sub-query that's the slow bit. I have the indexes specified by Quassnoi.

Comment: @Zeus: if we are talking about performance you should specify the query exactly as it is. Every of these 130 lines can matter.

Comment: @Quassnoi you may be correct... I have the same join in the original procedure. Without it, the procedure takes a few seconds, with it, it takes minutes. Which is why I attempted to present this simplified example. I was hoping there was something wonky with the join syntax :)

Answer (score 1):

Make a join against the table instead of a subquery, that should give the query preprocessor better freedom to make the best joins.

```
select p.peopleID, p.peopleName, pe.DataNumber
from peopleTable p
left join (
  formElements fe
  inner join peopleExtra pe on pe.ElementID = fe.FormElementID
) on pe.peopleID = p.peopleID
where fe.FormComponentID = 42
```

Comment: This query will filter out the people who has no `FormComponentID = 42`. Besides, `SQL Server`'s optimizer is smart enough to deal with subqueries without rewriting them.